# Is file descriptor table necessary?

Tags: unix, filesystems, file-descriptor, inode

According to what I have read,  processes get a  fd that indexes into user fd table that in turn returns a pointer into  file table that maintains offset, pointer to inode and other properties of the opened file. So fd is basically maintaining a way to access file on disk, its position in the file. So cant commands like open directly return pointer into file table rather than going through the indirection of user fd table?  Is it there for security or for some other reason, or have i understood this wrong? [image]

Comment: Isnt fd table allocated for every new process and file table the global table in the kernel?

Comment: That's it. A table in the kernel is necessary to be able to track every open file in the system and manage all of this correctly, and at least some information is needed in the user space of the process.

Comment: User space needs to know the file table entries for the files it has opened so y dont system calls directly give a pointer to that instead of going through user fd table

Comment: Because you can't have a user space pointer pointing to something in the kernel.

Comment: If the program is in user mode the kernel wont allow access to the kernel memory,  however if uintptr a = open(..); read(a,buffer,sizeof(buffer) the program would go into kernel mode for system calls which will allow the access to kernel 
 memory, so wldnt having a pointer simplify one step for the kernel?

Comment: Why would it simplify? An int or a pointer would necessitate the same operations. But using a pointer would mean that the kernel is mapped into the address space of the process, which is probably a too strong constraint on implementation.